# Resource sharing in nested Parallel.For loop C#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.for

**Background**

I have a piece of code which is highly parallelizable and I found that most of the time I am using only one core at 100% while the rest does nothing. To tackle this I've tinkered with multithreading, implementing semaphores and what not to realize that Parallel.For() is fine grained and more efficient than any of my solutions.

**The Code**

To simplify I will only write the pieces of code structurally important.

```
int sharedResource = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < someMax; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        if (someCondition(i, j))
            sharedResource += someFunction(i, j);
        else break;
    }
}
```

All of the ambiguously named functions are more or less just mathematical equations and are of time complexity O(1).

**Important Details**

Pay attention to the inner loop that has the variable ***i*** as upper boundary as well as the summation variable named ***sharedResource***. The execution order in this case is not important as addition is commutative and I don't see any obvious reason for **Amdahl's Law** to apply as all instance combinations (i, j) of both loops can be calculated independently.

**Question**

Is it smart to use a nested Parallel.For() loop in this scenario or should I only use it instead of the outer loop (or only on the inner respectively)?

The only thing that concerns me is the **sharedResource** as I don't get a lot of in-depth insight of how Parallel.For() works from the documentation. Another important thing is that if I do use two Parallel.For() loops some instances will finish almost instantly due to the **break** while others will take much more time. Will it be able to balance this?

Comment: Shared resource is not thread safe because of assignment operator

Comment: Why don't you simply tried it?

Comment: Because it might work false positively and I need a concrete answer. Figuring out why the program fails after a few days due to non thread safe code can be a debugging nightmare @Eser

Comment: Just create `ConcurrentBag<int>` (assuming your shared resource is an int) which is thread safe and add your results to the bag. After the `Parallel.For` has finished - sum the results.

Comment: And how long does it take on average to complete one iteration of inner loop?

Comment: The overall complexity is about n log (n). Depending on the input this can vary between a few micro seconds and a couple seconds or more. (the inner loop that is). On random input its a milisecond tops.

Comment: @Ilhan  `Because it might work false positively and I need a concrete answer.` So If say "do it this way" you will code it and assume it is correct? Better, first try it and then ask your question with the codes you have tried so far

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius No. suppose a silly question of summing up values from 1 to 1 billion in parallel (without using gauss method n*(n+1)/2) would you add all of the intermediate results to a collection. (see for ex the usage of *Interlocked* class in below answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether to use nested parallel loops, parallelize only inner or only outer loop, depends a lot on nature of your data. Nested parallel loops are designed to work reasonably well. For example, if both outer and inner loops has both degree of parallelism of 8 for example - it does not mean that when nested they will process items on 8x8=64 threads, as one might think when looking naively at this.

You should measure perfomance of all options on your specific data set and figure out what works best for you.

Note that `Parallel.For` loop partitions interval in certain number of ranges (depending on degree of parallelism) and then those ranges are executed in parallel on separate threads. What that means is: if processing time of your items is distributed non-evenly - some ranges might complete much faster than others. Say you run with degree of parallelism 4, and processing 100 items, of which first 75 return `false` for `someCondition` and so take 0 time to execute, while last 25 return `true`. In result, first 3 ranges will complete immediately and last range with all real work will execute on one thread, essentially making whole thing sequential.

If uneven distribution is expected, you might use `Parallel.ForEach` with "real" `IEnumerable` instead (by real I mean it's not array or list but real "lazy" `IEnumerable`):

```
Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, i), j => {...})
```

But note that on evenly distributed data it will be slower than pre-partitioned version.

Nested `Parallel.For` might also help if run-time is unevenly distributed, but again - you have to measure each option on your real data and choose the best one.

As for thread safety. Of course, this

```
sharedResource += someFunction(i, j);
```

is not thread safe inside parallel loops. Using `lock` here might degrade perfomance a lot if `someFunction` is fast, and not necessary anyway. Either just use

```
Interlocked.Add(ref sharedResource, someFunction(i, j))
```

Or you can use overloads of `Parallel.For``Parallel.ForEach` which allow accumulation of values per each running thread, and then aggregation of results. For example:

```
Parallel.For(0, 100, (i, outerState) =>
{
   Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, i), () => 0, (j, innerState, subTotal) =>
   {
       if (someCondition(i, j))
           return subTotal + someFunction(i, j);
       else {
           innerState.Break();
           return subTotal;
       }
   }, subTotalOfThread => Interlocked.Add(ref sharedResource, subTotalOfThread));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some custom partitioner with load balancing enabled and use it in `Parallel.ForEach` loop. Load balancing assures that every core is busy until the end of execution. For example:

```
int sharedResource = 0;
var iterations = Enumerable.Range(0, someMax);

//this creates partitioner with load balancing (true is default for IEnumerable really)
var customPartitioner = Partitioner.Create(iterations, true); 

Parallel.ForEach(customPartitioner, i =>
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        if (someCondition(i, j))
            Interlocked.Add(ref sharedResource, someFunction(i, j)); 
        else break;
    }
});
```

In your example an assignment operator is really not thread safe so I used `Interlocked.Add` instead.

You can also write some functional code which can be parallelized by design with LINQ. Note that there is no any shared resource or thread synchronization because there is no state in FP.

```
var result = customPartitioner
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(i => Enumerable.Range(0, i + 1)
        .AsParallel()
        .TakeWhile(j => someCondition(i, j))
        .Sum(j => someFunction(i, j)))
    .Sum();
```

One thing you also need to take into account is thread creation cost. The more thread you create the more processor's time is wasted on it instead of doing actual work. Also *Parallel.Foreach* provides additional cost in determining on which thread each iteration should run. So sometimes it's better to have some inner loop single-threaded . In LINQ example in some cases inner `AsParallel` may provide additional cost really.

Comment: I would remove the inner loop and do it in a single `Parallel.For`